# How to trigger canvas drawing line animation without actual mouse move?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am currently figuring out how to draw lines on page load without even having to actually moving the mouse to draw

Here is my code which draws line only when mouse is moved.

https://codepen.io/arvi/pen/RgYZqB

I added a "load" event listener and tied it to documentMouseMoveHandler but it seems not the solution for this scenario.

```
window.addEventListener('load', documentMouseMoveHandler, false);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: its taking mouse pointer to draw the line right, if you dont want mouse pointer then upto where it will draw???

Comment: @Durga, the client wants it to draw randomly on page load without moving the mouse. As you noticed, it only draws when you move the mouse. I've also tried simulating mouse move via javascript but it seems to only detect real mouse moves. I'm honestly clueless :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok do something like this until you get a mouse event , take random moue point in a interval if mouse event came, then remove it;

```
var intervalId;
function documentMouseMoveHandler(event) {
  if (!event) {
    intervalId = setInterval(function () {
       mouseX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (window.innerWidth - 1));
       mouseY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (window.innerHeight + 1));
      }, 3000);
    return;
  }
  if (event && intervalId) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }

  mouseX = event.clientX - (window.innerWidth - SCREEN_WIDTH) * .5;
  mouseY = event.clientY - (window.innerHeight - SCREEN_HEIGHT) * .5;
}`
```

Comment: here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/durga598/pen/YQOrvM) , its not listening to load event , because page is already loaded it seems, so i called from script only,

Comment: great solution. Thanks a lot. I appreciate it.